# Can't remove additional keyboard in Windows 10, because it's not shown in the list

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have this problem that I've been shown two different keyboards that I can literally switch between them:

[image]

But I don't want the second keyboard, and I want to remove it and install another language's keyboard. However, when I click on `Language preferences`, I don't see the second keyboard in the list:

[image]

Is there another way to manage keyboards? Like regedit, or command line, or any other way that I can solve this problem?

Comment: Open **Control Panel** and navigate to *Clock, Language, and Region* -> *Language*. Is there any other language in there?

Comment: @iTechieGamer, only one language. The second one is missing.